# sclar-valued function in sql

Tags: sql, join, subquery

```
select Pending = PD.Qty - (select sum(GRND.Qty)  
from tbl_GRN GRN inner join tbl_GRND GRND on
GRN.grnId = GRND.grnId where GRN.pivID=PD.pivID and GRND.prodId=PD.prodId)
from tbl_PD PD where PD.pivId=10609
```

Hai, we are developing a stock maintenance project.
The above is query used by me to get the pending quantity of a product. The query is giving the required results. But PD.Qty and GRND.Qty may be in different scale(units). So we are making use of a vector function ConvertScale that converts the scale. Its parameters are `ConvertScale(@Qty, @InputScale, @OutputScale)` and return the quantity in the vale of OutputScale.

where to add

```
ConvertScale(@GRND.Qty, @GRND.ScaleID, @PD.ScaleID)
```

Please tell me the changes to be made in query.

Comment: Tag the dbms you're using. (That code is product specific.)

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Answer (score 0):

Do not prefix columns with @. My guess you are after the query

```
select Pending = PD.Qty - 
  (select sum(ConvertScale(GRND.Qty, GRND.ScaleID, PD.ScaleID))  
   from tbl_GRN GRN 
   inner join tbl_GRND GRND on GRN.grnId = GRND.grnId 
   where GRN.pivID=PD.pivID and GRND.prodId=PD.prodId)
from tbl_PD PD where PD.pivId=10609
```